# Append text to ObjectProperty

Tags: python, kivy

I have `text_from_file = ObjectProperty(None)` and I read a file line by line using

```
    def load_list(self, path, filename):
    with open(filename[0], 'r') as file:
        line = file.readline()
        cnt = 1
        while line:
            print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line.strip()))
            line = file.readline()
            cnt += 1
            self.text_from_file.text = "{}".format(line.strip())
    self.dismiss_popup()
```

The problem is that `self.text_from_file.text = "{}".format(line.strip())` is overwritten every time and I need to append text to the `text_from_file.text`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the last line to this: `self.text_from_file.text += "{}".format(line.strip())`

Comment: So simple solution, I have tried it before but I had `line.strip()` missing. Thanks

Comment: @mrRobot No problem. Happy coding... :o)